# Beamer: print slides and notes on A4 paper correctly

Tags: beamer, margins, printing, pgfpages

Following up on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193277/printing-a-handout-of-a-beamer-presentation-the-resulting-pdf-is-shrunk), I have the MWE example below, that works well except for when I want to print the resulting `pdf`, which becomes completely shrunk ... so small that I cannot read the letters. I cannot hand this in!

What is the problem here? I have tried every possibility, as you can see in the MWE (not specifying the A4 paper, using `letterpaper` instead, play with margins in cm and inches...)

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[handout, ignorenonframetext, xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\reserveinserts{28}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[]
%\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper]
%\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[letterpaper]
%\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
%\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[letterpaper,border shrink=0.5in]
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=bottom} % Beamer manual, section 19.3
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=pink}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain] % Beamer manual, section 19.1
\newlength{\parskipbackup}
\setlength{\parskipbackup}{\parskip}
\newlength{\parindentbackup}
\setlength{\parindentbackup}{\parindent}
\newcommand{\baselinestretchbackup}{\baselinestretch}

\usetemplatenote{

  %\insertslideintonotes{0.3}%

  \rmfamily \scriptsize%
  \setlength{\parindent}{1em} \setlength{\parskip}{1ex}%
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}%

  \insertnote%

  \setlength{\parskip}{\parskipbackup}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{\parindentbackup}%
  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{\baselinestretchbackup}%
}



\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
Title slide
\note{this is a note}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
This is the first slide
\note{this is another note}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The `pdf` produced looks flawless on screen:

[image: flawless on screen]

But look at the print preview (which is printed in the same way)... and this happens with *every program I have tried, in both Ubuntu and Windows* (Acrobat included), so it's a LaTeX problem...

[image: shrunk print preview]

Please help!

Note I want both the `pdf` on screen and when printed to look as it should... I don't want to enlarge the `pdf` on screen so it is printed correctly...

Comment: please consider accepting the answer, if it has solved the problem (in my case, it had ;)

Answer (score 2):

I guess, this can be solved by applying appropriate printing properties. For example in Adobe Reader select the `Fit` option and it prints nicely.

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

For Okular, try the `Trim Margins` option.

[image]

Comment: Do you know of any program that can do the same in Ubuntu? Okular doesn't seem to be able to do so...
In any case, shouldn't the actual size be the correct one, since I specify a4paper in the latex script?