# Beamer: Trying to print a handout with notes, and it shrinks to like half the size

Tags: beamer, margins, printing, notes, handout

I am refloating [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193277/printing-a-handout-of-a-beamer-presentation-the-resulting-pdf-is-shrunk) and will give a good bounty if somebody can solve it, cause it has been bothering me for the longest time, and cannot find a solution to it...

I have some problems when trying to make my **Beamer presentations in handout format with notes**, for printing and study them before the presentation day.

While the PDF seems to be generated with no problem, when trying to print it **IT SHRINKS**, and this happens with **ALL THE PDF VIEWERS I HAVE TRIED**, including Okular and Acrobat... This tells me that there is an inherent problem with the PDF itself...

This is the MWE I currently use:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=bottom}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=pink}

\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme{Singapore}
}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage  
\note{
    Notes for the title page
}
\end{frame}


\section*{Outline}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents

\note{
    Notes for the table of contents
}
\end{frame}


\section{Frame 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame with notes 1}
    FIRST FRAME CONTENTS

\note{
    Notes for the first frame
}
\end{frame}


\section{Frame 2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame with notes 2}
    SECOND FRAME CONTENTS
\note{
    Notes for the second frame
}
\end{frame}


\section{Frame 3}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame with notes 3}
    SECOND FRAME CONTENTS
    \note{
        Notes for the third frame
    }
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

When I open the PDF with Okular, for example, it seems to open correctly (though the navigation links do not work):

[image: a]

But just going to the PRINT PREVIEW (same when actually printing), look what happens:

[image: b]

It shrinks to like half the size, and it has nothing to do with my printing properties, or with the printer...

Please help!!

Comment: You wailing about the navigation links is totally off-topic for this question!

Comment: That's why I provide a link to the question that focuses on the topic, cause the output of the MWE still shows those navigation problems...

Comment: But isn't it totally irrelevant for this question?

Comment: Yes it is... lol

Comment: Then why not remove the entire paragraph?

Comment: already removed